# How to get top-n accuracy?

Tags: machine-learning

Is there a way to get the top-3 or top-5 accuracies per class from a model using `ClassifierMeasurements[]`?

Comment: Could you define / point to a definition for those quantities?

Comment: @marcob In top-5 accuracy you give yourself credit for having the right answer if the right answer appears in your top five guesses.

Comment: @user5601 Your question is vague or you do not clearly understand your problem. `ClassifierMeasurements[]` measures performance of the classifier. It doesn't do actual classification in a strict sense that you're trying to get. If you have a plethora of classes, then, as mentioned, "TopProbabilities" will return n best classifications. `Ceiling[percentage*Length@classes]` will give you that n. 
If, on the other hand, you are looking for best classified examples, you can use CM's "BestClassifiedExamples", "MostCertainExamples", or "Probabilities", again, use the n calculation for percentage.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I do not think what OP wants can be done through `ClassifierMeasurements` -- it has to be programmed with `Classify[___,"TopProbabilities"->_Integer]`.

Below is given one way to do the measure as defined in a comment:

> In top-5 accuracy you give yourself credit for having the right answer if the right answer appears in your top five guesses.

Assuming we have a classifier function `cf` and `testData` of the form `{instance->label..}` we can use this function:

```
TopNClassifierMeasure[cf_ClassifierFunction, testData_, n_Integer] := 
 Tally@Map[
   MemberQ[cf[#[[1]], "TopProbabilities" -> n][[All, 1]], #[[2]]] &, 
   testData]

TopNClassifierMeasure[cf, testData, 3]
(* {{True, 9}, {False, 1}} *)
```

Here is a screenshot of using that function with a digit classifier from [`Classify`'s function page](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Classify.html):
[image]